# data from didSelectRowAtIndexPath not available in prepareForSegue (swift)

Tags: swift

The data I need (`selectedPlaylistToPass`) is showing up correctly in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but not in `prepareForSegue`.  The receiving view controller obviously doesn't receive the data either.  What am I doing wrong?

```
    var selectedPlaylistToPass = NSString()

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedPlaylist = tableData.collections![indexPath.row]
    let selectedPlaylistToPass = selectedPlaylist.valueForProperty(MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName) as! NSString
    print("selected: \(selectedPlaylistToPass)")   //SHOWS IN CONSOLE CORRECT
    performSegueWithIdentifier("playlistSongsView" as String, sender: self)
}

override func   prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    print("selected: \(selectedPlaylistToPass)")  //SHOWS IN CONSOLE AS "selected:   "
    if(segue.identifier == "playlistSongsView") {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! playlistSongsViewController
        vc.selectedPlaylistToPass = self.selectedPlaylistToPass as String
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You was initializing new variable in `let selectedPlaylistToPass`. Try this code

```
var selectedPlaylistToPass = NSString()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedPlaylist = tableData.collections![indexPath.row]
    self.selectedPlaylistToPass = selectedPlaylist.valueForProperty(MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName) as! NSString
    print("selected: \(selectedPlaylistToPass)")
    performSegueWithIdentifier("playlistSongsView" as String, sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    print("selected: \(selectedPlaylistToPass)")
    if(segue.identifier == "playlistSongsView") {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! playlistSongsViewController
        vc.selectedPlaylistToPass = self.selectedPlaylistToPass as String
    }
}
```